# How to reach Custom Preferences items from Fragment?

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

In my application Settings Layout i need custom preference for profile Category. I searched and done something .

**pref.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Profil">


    <Preference
        android:key="custom"
        android:title="My Custom Preferenece"
        android:layout="@layout/custom">

    </Preference>

    <Preference
        android:icon="@drawable/transparency"
        android:key="email"
        android:selectable="false"
        android:summary=""
        android:title="Email"           
        />
```

**custom.xml** (i used for preference layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:background="@android:color/white"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >       
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/custom_image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/no_photo"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        />


    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView            
        android:id="@+id/custom_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Custom Text"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:gravity="center"            
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to reach and set android:id="@+id/custom_image" or android:id="@+id/custom_text" , i didn't reach these items from my fragment.
How can i reach these items from fragment ?

Thank you

**My fragment**

```
public class GeneralPreferenceFragmentN  extends PreferenceFragment  {

private Context mContext;

@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_main);
    mContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();       

    bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("phone"));

    private static void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) 
      {

      preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(
      sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener);

    SharedPreferences prefs = preference.getSharedPreferences();
    Object value;


    if (preference instanceof MultiSelectListPreference) {
        value = prefs.getStringSet(preference.getKey(), new HashSet<String>
      ());
    } else {
        value = prefs.getString(preference.getKey(), "");
    } 
    ..................
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

in your onCreate() initialize the view:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_abschliessen_einsatz, container, false);


    //@INFO:   Create a global View v element if you want to use the view in other funtions (for example on slected and so on). Otherwise just use  
    this.v = v;

    //@INFO:    Otherwise just use th View elemnt to to find by ID
    myCustomImage = (AppCompatImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.custom_image);
    myCustomText = (AppCompatTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.custom_text);

   //Set Text or do stuff with the elements afterwards

    return v;
    }

    //Use the view in other fuctions, ex. onSelcted
    @Override
    public void onSelected() {
        //update UI when selected

        //@INFO:    Use the global View elemnt to to find by ID
        myCustomImage = (AppCompatImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.custom_image);
        myCustomText = (AppCompatTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.custom_text);

       //Set Text or do stuff with the elements afterwards

}
```

Comment: I did but it returns error   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapplication.activities.SettingsActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class